# Problem understanding a property of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a book by W. Fulton about algebraic geometry, and it states a property as follows:

> $I(V (I(X))) = I(X)$ for any
>   set $X$ of points. So if $I$ is the ideal of an
>   algebraic set, $I = I(V (I))$.

But aren't this things the same, because if $I$ is the ideal of an algebraic set, ($I=I(X)$ where $X$ is algebraic) then

$$I(X)=I(V(I(X)))$$

Which is exactly what the first part told me in general, why is it necessary to specify the case when $X$ is algebraic?

Comment: I think the difference can be seen when $I$ is just an ideal in $K[X_1,\dots, X_n]$, not necessarily the ideal of an algebraic set (albeit any ideal defines an algebraic set).  In this case the *Nullstellensatz* asserts that $\;I(V(I))=\sqrt I$.

Answer (score 1):

The author is most likely repeating the concept with the intent of stressing on the fact that $I(V(I))$ does not hold for all ideals, but just for some of them. It's noteworthy that we do not lose generality in assuming that $X$ is an algebraic set: for all $X\subseteq k^n$ there is some algebraic set $Y$ such that $I(X)=I(Y)$; namely, $Y=V(I(X))$ as the author has just pointed out.